# Recurlyv3 API doesn't find any data associated with valid token id

Tags: php, ajax, recurly

This is the essential bit of PHP:

```
// Add subscription
$subscription = new Recurly_Subscription();
$subscription->plan_code = $planCode;
$subscription->currency = 'USD';
$subscription->quantity = 1;

if ($couponCode != "") { $subscription->coupon_code = $couponCode; }

$subscription->account = new Recurly_Account();
$subscription->account->account_code = $customerID;

$subscription->billing_info = new Recurly_BillingInfo();
$subscription->account->billing_info->token_id = $token;

$subscription->create();
```

When this code runs, `$token` has the `tokenID` created by an earlier call to recurly.token (...) with the billing info.

The account already exists on Recurly -- the account ID, first and last names, but no billing info. This is because we allow people to signup for a complimentary service before subscribing. So I want to create the subscription on the extant account. Initially, following the code examples, the `create()` call was `subscription->account->create()`. But that failed because the account existed already.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue with the old PHP library, which did not support tokenization of billing information. An upgrade to the PHP client library should fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what we found out the hard way. Thanks, Rachel.